# insert all and inner join in oracle

Tags: oracle, join, inner-join, sql-insert, oracle12c

I would like to insert data in to two tables. Will be one-to-many connection. For this, I have to use Foreign Key, of course.

I think, table1 - ID column is an ideal for this a Primary Key. But I generate it always with a trigger, automatically, every line. SO, 
How can I put Table1.ID (auto generated, Primary Key) column in to table2.Fkey column in the same insert query?

```
INSERT ALL INTO table1 (   --here (before this) generated the table1.id column automatically with a trigger.
    table1.food,
    table1.drink,
    table1.shoe
) VALUES (
    'apple',
    'water',
    'slippers'
)
 INTO table2 (
    fkey,
    color
) VALUES (
    table1.id, -- I would like table2.fkey == table1.id this gave me error
    'blue'
) SELECT
    *
  FROM
    table1
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.fkey;
```

The error message:
"`00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"`"

Comment: Can you use a sequence to create the id?

Comment: The error message should also show the identifier Oracle deems "invalid". Can you find it and post back (add at the bottom of your question)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Oracle DB's 12c version, then might use `Identity Column Property`. Then easily return the value of first table's (*table1*) to a local variable by charging of `returning` clause just after an insert statement for *table1*, and use inside the next insert statement which is for *table2* as stated below :

```
SQL> create table table1(
  2                      ID    integer generated always as identity primary key,
  3                      food  varchar2(50), drink varchar2(50), shoe varchar2(50)
  4                      );

SQL> create table table2(
  2                      fkey  integer references table1(ID),
  3                      color varchar2(50)
  4                      );

SQL> declare
  2    cl_tab table1.id%type;
  3  begin
  4    insert into table1(food,drink,shoe) values('apple','water','slippers' )
  5    returning id into cl_tab;
  6    insert into table2 values(cl_tab,'blue');
  7  end;     
  8  /

SQL> select * from table1;

ID  FOOD    DRINK   SHOE
-- ------- ------- -------
 1  apple   water  slippers

SQL> select * from table2;

FKEY COLOR
---- --------------------------------------------------
   1 blue
```

Anytime you issue the above statement for insertions between *begin* and *end*, both `table1.ID` and `table2.fkey` columns will be populated by the same integer values. By the way do not forget to *commit* the changes by insertions, if you need these values throughout the DB(i.e.from other sessions also).

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @OldProgrammer, use sequence

```
INSERT ALL INTO table1 (   --here (before this) generated the table1.id column automatically with a trigger.
    table1_id,
    table1.food,
    table1.drink,
    table1.shoe
) VALUES (
    <sequecename_table1>.nextval,
    'apple',
    'water',
    'slippers'
)
 INTO table2 (
    fkey,
    color
) VALUES (    
    <sequecename_table2>.nextval,
    <sequecename_table1>.currval, -- returns the current value of a sequence.
    'blue'
) SELECT
    *
  FROM
    table1
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.fkey;
```